# Is it possible to say view the value of cell A3 in the input box text?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to say view the current value of cell `A3` in the `inputbox` text?

This is what I'm using.

```
Dim strValue As String  
strValue = Application.InputBox("A3 <- Is the current value, Enter new value", "Value A3")  
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = strValue
```

Answer (score 3):

`Application.InputBox` includes a default parameter as the third argument so use this to place the current value directly in the box

```
Dim strValue As String
strValue = Application.InputBox("Enter new value", "Hello World", [a3].Value, , , , , 1)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = strValue
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim s As String
    s = "Current value in A3 is " & Range("A3").Text & " ;enter a new value"
    Range("A3").Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:=s)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Nice one Gary :) But both the answers need to handle `False` part of the InputBox